# terminationgraceperiodseconds not working as expected

Tags: kubernetes

My aim is to gracefully terminate my REST application Pods. I have 2 pods running and  when 1 Pod is deleted, requests should be gracefully migrated to other pods. I am using Minikube (v1.20.0)for testing with Jmeter script running 100 API calls. I have also added a delay of 3 seconds inside my API.
I tried to set value of terminationgraceperiodseconds to 60 but learnt that pod was getting deleted within 30 seconds and there were some failures in my jemeter test requests.
I tried reducing value of terminationgraceperiodseconds  to 10 seconds and saw that Pod gets deleted within 10 seconds.

Next I read about preStop hook and I added a preStop hook with sleep time as 15 seconds. With this change, my requests started gracefully migrating to other pods even if i deleted the pod which was swerving requests.

I would like to know why parameter terminationgraceperiodseconds whose value set to 60 seconds is taking 30 seconds to terminate the pod. Any other settings I need to change ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is working as expected! when you kill/delete a pod a SIGTERM signal is sent to the pod. kubernetes waits up to "terminationgraceperiodseconds" for the pod to shutdown normally after receiving the SIGTERM.

after terminationgraceperiodseconds has passed and the pod has shutdown itself then kubernetes will send a SIGKILL signal, killing the pod without waiting for it to gracefully shutdown.

so if your pod is terminated after 30 seconds while you have 60 seconds configured for terminationgraceperiodseconds that just means, that the pod shutdown its processes after 30 seconds.

Comment: Ok, i was expecting  this but then  what I can do to ensure that when value of terminationgraceperiodseconds is 60, pod deletion takes 60 Seconds.   One way I can do this is to add preStop hook with delay  say 55 or 58  sec ?
Also, when i had terminationgraceperiodseconds  value as 60seconds and did not have prestop hook delay, i observed failures in Jmete REST call, response of failed API was 404. Does that means terminationgraceperiodseconds  has not respected gracefull shutdown of POD ?

Comment: i don't have a lot of experience with JMeter, however, I think that a rest call went to the pod, then he recieved the shutdown signal, and did not respond to the rest request due to not handling requests while shutting down. so he never sent a response.

Comment: also the behaviour you want to achieve simply isn't possible just with terminationgraceperiodseconds as it acts as a timeout before sending a kill signal, not to ensure that the shutdown takes exactly X seconds